# Xcode. The buttons aren't clickable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile

I've been searching through the internet for the last week and cannot find right answer for my situation.
I have several ViewControllers and two of them have buttons.
No problem with first one ("Follow" button) - I can click button on simulator.
But second one doesn't work as supposed to.
What I've tried to do:

1. Check a hierarchy of the app - looks right
2. Recreate connections between Views -  looks right as well.
3. User Interaction enabled
4. for click i have typical:

   @IBAction func clickStoryButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
   }

By the way when I tried to change background color for buttons -  it doesn't work on simulator, so I strongly believe that some layout is upper than my buttons, but still don't see which one..
[image: first image]
[image: second image]
[image: third image]
[image: fourth image]
[image: fifth image]

Comment: show the link for the button and your code to respond to it in your VC. お願いします。

Comment: added a screenshot

Comment: are you triggering a segue and trying to respond to the button at the same time? Try removing the segue.

Comment: sorry, didn't get what you mean: how I can move to another screen if I delete the segue

Comment: why do you want to call the button method if your intent is to segue?

Comment: but I have same logic with the button on the main screen and it works fine
I just have sound inside Action ( but it changes nothing cause I tried add sound to my problem button as well - same shit)
I added a screenshot with button which works fine ("Follow")

Answer (score 3):

for the color, I see you are trying to change the color for the stack view, where you can’t set a background color for the stack view. Either set the colour for the buttons individually or fo the stack views super view which in your case is the medium view.

Comment: Thanks about color - I knew about StackView, but thought it's possible for simple View in a StackView

Answer (score 2):

Try giving a height constraint for your stack view and set stack distribution to equally fill.

Comment: didn't help, added screenshots

Comment: @Oleg can we connect over skype?